# List of post SP2 hot fixes for Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

Does anyone know if there is a master list of post-SP2 hot fixes for Office 2007? I can find fragments here and there but not a comprehensive list. We've got a bit of instability and looking through the hot fix list might help.

Comment: Use IE windows updates to look in the view updates history list, or the add/remove programs list.

Answer (score 0):

See [kbupdate.info : Microsoft Knowledge Base monitoring](http://kbupdate.info/) :

> kbupdate.info is a monitoring system
>   that scans the entire Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base every night.

For example, this [list](http://kbupdate.info/word-2007-2010.php) contains all of the known Microsoft Knowledge Base articles, howtos, fixes, hotfixes, webcasts and updates of Microsoft Word 2007 that have been released in Year 2010.